# Dkms doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, kernel, dkms

Okay so I been trying to install windows in virtual box but when I try to start it I get kernel drive not installed. I have tried sudo apt install dkms but the problem still persists and when I try the setup command with vbox it says command not found. How do I fix this? I'm on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is Virtualization enables in BIOS?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message, and show me the output from the `terminal` of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii` and I'll see if I can help. Start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.